# how can I AJAX form authentication?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, openldap

I have a login screen with username and password credentials that are validated throught a php script. once a user enters their username and password and hits submit. authenticate.php does an LDAP bind and if the user's credentials are legit they are redirected to say www.siteA.com, if the credentials are false an erorr is given saying "Invalid login, authentication failed. I would like to make this AJAX so when a user hits submit, right on that page it tells the user whether they entered valid or invalid login.

Below is my code:

For login form:

```
<form action=authenticate.php method=post name=Auth class="appnitro">
    <div class="form_description">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>
<ul>
        <li id="li_1">
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Username </label>
        <div>
        input id="element_1" name="login" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
    </li>
        <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Password </label>
        <div>
        <input id="element_2" name="password" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
    </li>
        <li class="buttons">
            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My LDAP Bind, Authenticate.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
    {
        //LDAP stuff here.
        $username = trim($_POST['login']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        echo("Authenticating...");
        $ds = ldap_connect('ldap://ldap:port');

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        //Can't connect to LDAP.
        if( !ds )
        {
            echo "Error in contacting the LDAP server -- contact ";
            echo "technical services!  (Debug 1)";

            exit;
        }

        //Connection made -- bind anonymously and get dn for username.
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ds);

        //Check to make sure we're bound.
        if( !bind )
        {
            echo "Anonymous bind to LDAP FAILED.  Contact Tech Services! (Debug 2)";

            exit;
        }

        $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=keler,DC=medioa,DC=com", "uid=$username");

        //Make sure only ONE result was returned -- if not, they might've thrown a * into the username.  Bad user!
        if( ldap_count_entries($ds,$search) != 1 )
        {
            echo "Error processing username -- please try to login again. (Debug 3)";
            redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

            exit;
        }

        $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);

        //Now, try to rebind with their full dn and password.
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ds, $info[0][dn], $password);
        if( !$bind || !isset($bind))
        {
            echo "Login failed -- please try again. (Debug 4)";
            redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

            exit;
        }

        //Now verify the previous search using their credentials.
        $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=keler,DC=medioa,DC=com", "uid=$username");
        //if the user's login is legit then redirect to the siteA    
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
        if( $username == $info[0][uid][0] )
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $info[0][cn][0]; 
            header( "Location: www.siteA.com" );

            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error. Access Denied";
            redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

            exit;
        }
        ldap_close($ds);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to paste all that.

submit the form using Ajax, and have the server-side script return a status and error message.

if the status indicates the login was successful, do the redirect using JavaScript.

if the status indicates the login failed, alert the error message.

Comment: right now if its succesful, the login, php redirects, if i use ajax and use the property onclick for submit and login is sucessful will that work? if it fails then i simply print to html div the error?

Comment: I think you need to do a few Ajax tutorials to get a handle on it. From your answer, I am guessing you've never done it before. Ajax is (by definition) asynchronous, which can be a very tricky thing to get a handle on. Do a few tutorials, and it will become obvious to you.

Comment: ive only done an ajax tutorial where it fills the value of a textbox with server's time

Comment: do a few jQuery tutorials that specifically concentrate on Ajax; especially if they're interactive in any way, such as creating a chat server.

Comment: i have made an ajax chatroom where all the log is written in html and its read off, i just am stuck with submitting it through ajax

Comment: do a few jQuery tutorials. $.post() can be used to submit data.